# How to define a class with mutually exclusive members/fields in Python3/Pydantic

Tags: json, rust, fastapi, python-3.9, pydantic

I have a class called `GeoLocation` with  fields (point and region) that are mutually exclusive.
How do I define the class?

Python3 code:

```py
from enum import Enum
from typing import Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Point(BaseModel):
    latitude: float
    longitude: float

class Ellipse(BaseModel):
    center: Point
    semiMajorAxis: Optional[float] = None

# point and region are mutually exclusive. Exactly one must be present.
class GeoLocation(BaseModel):
    point:Ellipse
    region:Polygon
    confidence: Optional[int] = None
```

Expected json output after serialization:

```json
{
"location": {
      "point": {
       "center": {"latitude": 37.0, "longitude": -101.3}
              }
       }
}
```

How do I define the `GeoLocation` class in `python3` or [pydantic](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/) such that `point` and `region` are mutually exclusive?
I was able to implement this in `Rust` by defining an `enum` of with two `struct` as shown below.

Rust Code

```rust
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
#[serde(rename_all = "lowercase")]
pub enum Loc {
    Point(Ellipse),
    Region(Polygon),
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct GeoLocation {
    #[serde(flatten)]
    pub loc: Loc, // point and region are  mutually exclusive

    #[serde(skip_serializing_if = "Option::is_none")]
    pub confidence: Option<Int>, // OPTIONAL
}
```

Can I define an `enum` of classes in python3? Something like the following code. If yes, how do I initialize `Loc`

```py
class Ellipse(BaseModel):
    center: Point
    semiMajorAxis: Optional[float] = None

class Polygon(BaseModel):
    exterior: Point

# Note: point and region are mutually exclusive.  
# Exactly one must be present.
class Loc(Enum):
    point = Ellipse
    region = Polygon

class GeoLocation(BaseModel):
    loc: Loc
    confidence: Optional[int] = None
```

Thanks

Comment: Given that you have the `loc` key as the enum value, would `loc: Union[Ellipse, Polygon]` or on 3.10: `loc: Ellipse | Polygon` be the same? `loc` would be either an Ellipse or a Polygon, but not both? Otherwise I would think that you'd need a validator to enforce that one of the fields has to be None.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the `loc` field as an enum value, this wouldn't be any different from using the `Union` typing class (or in Python 3.10, using the typing or operator, `|`).

```
class GeoLocation(BaseModel):
    loc: Union[Ellipse, Polygon]  # loc: Ellipse | Polygon,
```

This should give you the same structure as in your Rust example.